# Spring unit test - using @ContextConfiguration when extending class in other project

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit

I have a spring unit test that extends other test located in other project (tests-common).
My context file (my-context.xml) is located in the same package as MyTest.
The base context file ("base-context.xml") is located in the same package as BaseTest.
The files looks like:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "my-context.xml"}) 
public class MyTest extends BaseTest {

@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "base-context.xml" })
public abstract class BaseTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests{
```

The issue is: `BaseTest` finds "base-context.xml" but `MyTest` gets `FileNotFoundException` for "my-context.xml".
If I move BaseTest and my-context.xml files to the same package as BaseTest - everything works fine.
What can be the problem?

Comment: can you try prefixing `classpath:` to the file names?

Answer (score 3):

Check out this in the spring documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-app-ctx

I would add the "classpath:" keyword in front of the base-context.xml and define the path relative to the classpath. 
You should also put your xml files in a subdirectory src/main/resources and not next to the java files.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned below you can use the classpath keyword like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:**/base-context.xml" })
```